# Using induction to prove an exponential lower bound for the Fibonacci sequence

Tags: proof-writing, induction, fibonacci-numbers

> The Fibonacci sequence $F_0, F_1, F_2,...,$ is defined by the rule:
>   $$F_0=0, F_1=1, F_n=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}$$
>   Use induction to prove that $F_n\geq2^{0.5n}$ for $n\geq 6$

---

So far I have done the basis step plugging in $6$ and getting $8$ in return.
Next I do the inductive step now I have $F_{k+1}=F_k+F_{k-1}$ and use the $F_n\geq2^{0.5n}$ they gave me I end up with $$2^{\frac{n}{2}}+2^{\frac{n-1}{2}}$$
at which point I get stuck I try and simplify the expression but what I end up with is different from the solutions. Can someone walk me throught this proof and explain how to do it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is almost finished. But for the induction to work, we also need to verify the inequality for $n=7$.

After that, all we need to do is to prove that
$$2^{\frac{n}{2}}+2^{\frac{n-1}{2}}\gt 2^{\frac{n+1}{2}}.$$
Equivalently, we want to show that
$$1+2^{-1/2} \gt 2^{1/2}.$$
Calculator!

Comment: why is the inequality sign flipped?

Comment: We want to prove that $F_{n+1} \gt 2^{(n+1)/2}$. We know that $F_n\gt 2^{n/2}$ and $F_{n-1}\gt 2^{(n-1)/2}$. So $F_{n+1}\gt 2^{n/2}+2^{(n-1)/2}$. If we can prove that this sum is $\gt 2^{(n+1)/2}$, we will have the result.

Comment: also when i try and verify 7 i dont get the right answer $2^{7/2}$ = 11.31 not 13 as it should

Comment: This is consistent with the desired result. We want to prove that $F_n\gt 2^{n/2}$. And indeed $13=F_7\gt 2^{7/2}\approx 11.3$.

Comment: You are welcome. That's what MSE is about.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $2^{\frac{n}{2}} + 2^{\frac{n-1}{2}} < 2^{\frac{n}{2}} + 2^{\frac{n}{2}}$.

Answer (score 1):

Induct on n:

Base case, n=6:
$$F_6 >= 2^{0.5n}$$
$$13 >= 2^3$$

Inductive assumptions:
$$F_n >= 2^{0.5n}$$
$$F_{n-1} >= 2^{0.5(n - 1)}$$
$$n > 6$$

Recursive case:
$$F_{n+1} >= 2^{0.5(n + 1)}$$
$$F_n + F_{n - 1} >= 2^{0.5n} \cdot 2^{0.5}$$
$$\text{by the first inductive assumption, }$$
$$\text{and both factors on the right being no less than 1}$$
$$\text{the above is implied by:}$$
$$F_{n - 1} >= 2^{0.5}$$
$$\text{For } n > 6, 2^{0.5(n - 1)} >= 2^{0.5}$$
$$\text{so the above is implied by}$$
$$F_{n - 1} >= 2^{0.5(n - 1)}$$
$$\text{which is the second inductive assumption. QED.}$$